# invalid syntax in python when using turtle command

Tags: python, syntax-error

hello I am new into python and programming and i have an assignment due in 15 hours and i have finished it but everytime i run it says invalid syntax.

```
from turtle import*

student_grades=[]
the_number_of_grades=int(input('the number of grades that are going to be proccesed:')
                         
for d in range (the_number_of_grades) :

    student_grades=int(input('please input all of your grades:')

    student_grades.append(student_grades)

grade_point_average=round(sum(student_grades) /len(studnet_grades),2)

clear()
penup()
setpos(-10,180)
write('MY GRADE POINT AVERAGE=' +str(grade_point_average))
setpos(80,180)
if grade_point_average > 70:
    write('YOUR GRADE POINT AVERAGE IS V.GOOD')
elif grade_point_average > 50:
    write('YOUR GRADE POINT AVERAGE IS LOW')
else:
    write('YOU HAVE GOT YOUR FIRST WARNING!:')
          

Ssetpos(0,0)
pd()
goto(180,0)
goto(0,0)
goto(0,150)
goto(0,0)


for d in range (len(student_grades)) :
    goto((d+1)*20 , grades[d])
    dot(5, 'RED')
    write(student_grades[d],False,'centre')
ht()
```

tbh idk what to do in this problem.

Comment: You're missing a closing parentheses on this line. `student_grades=int(input('please input all of your grades:')` And this line `the_number_of_grades=int(input('the number of grades that are going to be proccesed:')`

Comment: For best results, include more of the relevant information. In particular, if there's an error message, include it in your question, since it will usually include useful clues